# Using architecture specific settings in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I wonder if there is a way to specify different **Optimization Levels** according to architecture in Xcode?

What I would like to do is to have a different `-OX` setting for armv6 compared to armv7 for iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Try this in your settings:

```
PER_ARCH_CFLAGS_armv7 = "-OX"
PER_ARCH_CFLAGS_armv6 = "-OY"
```

(change X & Y to your favorite optimization levels"

Comment: Will they override standard settings that are set by normal editor?

Comment: And where should I place them? In __Other C Flags__ under __Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language__ section?

Comment: Yes, put them under "Other C Flags". If you look at the build transcript, you'll see both settings are passed to the compiler. First the "Optimization Level" setting to be chosen from the popup
menu, than after some warning flags and the map file path, the value
defined by 'PER_ARCH_CFLAGS_xxx'. The latter arguments overwrite/override the former.  Oh, [here's the source of my answer](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/246772-optimization-level-per-compiler.html). :-)

Comment: http://i40.tinypic.com/34jel1f.png I found this way (by pressing the plus symbol beside the specified scheme in _Optimization Level_, maybe this did the trick? Where can I find the transcript of the compiler? Never saw that inside console..

Comment: that way will work too.  As for looking for the transcript of the compiler, just go to the "Log Navigator" in your project in XCode 4, you'll see a list of compiled files and when you select any line in that list, you'll see a widget on the right side which you can click and see the actual compile / link transcript lines.

Comment: Just checked compiler output and I had two differents -OX as intended while attaching an armv6 and an armv7 device.. thanks a lot!